# Redux-Toolkit: createAsyncThunk axios request is not sent

Tags: react-native, api, axios, request, redux-toolkit

I am using react native for frontend and django for backend of my application, but I can't make an api request with axios to login authentication.
I would like to know why the request is not made to the backend but is rejected.
The code fails during the request, up to which point it is executed.

userSlice:

```
import axios from "axios";
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";


const initialState = {
    isLoading:false,
    isSuccess:false,
    isError:false,
    message:"",
    userInfo: null
}

export const login = createAsyncThunk(
    'user/login',
    async (userData, thunkApi) => {
        try{
            const config = {
                headers:{
                    'Content-type':'application/json'
                }
            }
            
            const response = await axios.post(
                'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/login/',
                userData,
                config
            )
            
            return response.data
 
            
        }catch(error){
            return thunkApi.rejectWithValue(error.response?.data)
        }
    })

const userSlice = createSlice({
    name:"user",
    initialState,
    reducers:{
    },
    extraReducers: (builder) => {
        builder.addCase(login.pending, (state) => {
                state.isLoading = true
            })
        builder.addCase(login.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
                state.isLoading = false
                state.isSuccess = true
                state.userInfo = action.payload
            })
        builder.addCase(login.rejected, (state, action) => {
                state.isLoading = false
                state.isSuccess = true
                state.userInfo = null
                state.message = action.payload
            })
    }
})

export default userSlice.reducer
```

store:

```
import {configureStore, combineReducers} from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

import userReducer from './userSlice'

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    user: userReducer
})

export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: rootReducer
})


export default store
```

login dispatch:

```
const onPressHandler = () =>{
   dispatch(login({username, password}))
}
```

Comment: What error do you obtain?

Comment: the only error is "Rejected", when i try to make a request to my django backend it doesn't work but when I make a request to esternal api I get response normally. And also if I open react native app from the browser it work, the only problem is when i try to make the request from expo go app